# Explanation needed for this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

```
var p = this.getParams();
var pD = (o.params||{});
if (this.useJsonData) pD = (pD.jsonData||{});
this.cursor = (pD && pD[p.start]) ? pD[p.start] : 0;
```

And what is the difference between these two lines.

```
this.cursor = pD[p.start] || this.cursor || 0;
```

Is the first code fine or there is any fault in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line has a fault. What if pD is null? 
Also it will keep value of this.cursor that is true (not null or false, that is).

Otherwise, they are identical.

Comment: well, not necessarily identical. The first one always changes `this.cursor`, but the second one can potentially leave it unchanged.

Comment: Yup. Read twice, comment once.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Search for `conditional operator`, `logical operators` and `short-circuit evaluation`.